# Is it possible to have three stable liquid phases in a binary mixture?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, phase, liquids

With this system, it would be possible to have three liquid phases and two liquid-liquid coexistence regions at various compositions. Similar behaviour is common for solids such as alloys, sometimes with even more stable phases.

I have been searching for a liquid mixture with this behaviour, but haven't found any. Are there any liquid binary mixtures which exhibit this behaviour, or is there any physical reason why this isn't possible? Does it have something to to with the higher disorder liquids have compared to solids?

Comment: There was a similar question not long ago. I commented that triple points are known in liquid crystals. I have never seen a liquid triple point on a binary elemental phase diagram.

Comment: Ah, your similar question was over on Physics... So, how do you feel about liquid crystals vs binary liquids?

Comment: I have been looking for binary liquids specifically, but thanks for mentioning liquid crystals. It kind of makes sense that they appear in liquid crystals, since they are more ordered than liquids. Solid solutions like alloys can show even more complex behaviour, and it seems like it might have something to do with the higher order they have. The thing I'm interested about is whether there is some deep physical reason binary liquids don't exhibit this behaviour, or it is just very unlikely and doesn't appear in any mixtures researched so far.

Comment: I currently have (quickly checking) some 2270 papers on my hard drive on binary or ternary phase diagrams. Most are elemental diagrams, some small fraction are various salts (nitrates, sulfates, etc.) or oxides. I have never seen a diagram with a liquid triple point. Miscibility gaps are modeled by either a simple positive enthalpy of mixing or an 'associate' suggesting some preferred clustering at a specific ratio.